# Publishing Library using Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, publishing, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to publish an Android library using Kotlin DSL. I got some errors

```
val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(sourceSets.getByName("main").allSource) 
}
```

SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = artifactGroup
            artifactId = artifactID
            version = artifactVersion

            from(components["java"])
            artifact(sourcesJar.get())

            pom {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SoftwareComponentInternal with name 'java' not found.

These blocks are in the library module `build.gradle.kts`.
Gradle Version: 5.6.2

How can I solve these problems ?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Need to use android source sets.

```
val androidSourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(android.sourceSets.getByName("main").java.srcDirs)
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm exactly in the same situation as you

Comment: @ThanosFisherman I updated my question.

Comment: That doesn't solve it for me

Answer (score 2):

I had to apply the `java` plugin `apply plugin: "java"`, resp. add it like:

```
plugins {
 id 'java'
```

Get more infos around [SoftwareComponent in the official gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html#org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication:from(org.gradle.api.component.SoftwareComponent)).